# Woocommerce Multisite Get Orders from Another Site

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm creating a plugin to create reports for a WC multisite installation.

I would like to be able to use the plugin in the master site admin and get orders for all sites within the multisite installation.

I don't see a way to do this in the wc_get_orders WC function or any other documented way. Is this possible using the WordPress or WooCommerce APIs?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to call the `switch_to_blog($blog_id)` function before calling any WooCommerce functions, then `restore_current_blog()` once done.

Comment: hi mark i would be really interested to see this plugin in action do you have an example

Comment: switch_to_blog() doesn't give you access to Woocommerce functions unless you have Woocommerce installed on the current site as well, FYI.